# Am I going nuts or does this seem right?

Tags: arithmetic

Just wondering, it's been a long time since high school math for me. The the expression below make sense?

I have my doubts because I remember the laws of radicals saying something about division that contradicts the below.

$$
\sqrt{x} \cdot \sqrt{z/w} = \sqrt{(xz)/w}
$$

Comment: could always be both.

Answer (score 8):

It's correct if $x$ and $z$ are non-negative and $w$ is positive.

If $a,b \ge 0$ then $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}= \sqrt{ab}$.

If $w\ne 0$, then $x\cdot\dfrac z w = \dfrac{xz}{w}$.

You're using those two facts.